# Magento - Sending Fields via CURL

Tags: php, javascript, magento, curl

I'd like to be able to post the results of our contact form via CURL to our CRM. I have the CURL connection working, and all of the code worked out for that. I'm just trying to figure out a way to grab the information from this contact form and set the fields as a variable so that I can send that data via CURL.

[The form can be seen here.](http://www.myfoodstorage.com/contact_us)

The problem is that the form posts to the same URL and so I'm not sure of how I can collect these fields. I tried to use $_REQUEST but it didn't seem to work.

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, don't use $_REQUEST because you are effectively saying you don't care if a parameter comes from the URL ($_GET) or from a browser/HTTP request ($_POST). (making it easier to abuse)

Secondly, where did you try using $_REQUEST?  If it was the template for that page then $_REQUEST or $_POST would work.  If you tried doing that in some CMS page/content editor inside of Magento then you will not be able to do that.

You will need to either implement an extension with a front end controller to accept the post, or just make a block/template change where you can actually execute PHP.
Presumably this is wherever you 'already have the CURL connection working'.